# how to swipe to right or left with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to swipe to right or left, but there's no button or element to click on it to swipe. The only option I have is to swipe to left or right is to hold the mouse and go to each side to swipe. 
I've tried this method but it doesn't work for me:

```
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.clickAndHold(homePage.HeroImage).build().perform();
        //you need to release the control from the test
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        action.moveToElement(homePage.HeroNext).release();
```

Thanks for your help :)
(`HeroImage` is the image that is showing now and `HeroNext` is the next image that i want to scroll into and both are visible)

I also tried this code, but it doesn't work either.

```
        try {

            for (int kk=0; kk<=6; kk++){
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
                scrollObject.put("direction", "right");
                js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
            }
            System.out.println("Swipe Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Image swipe was not successfull");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried doing your build and perform at the end?

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.clickAndHold(homePage.HeroImage);
    //you need to release the control from the test
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    action.moveToElement(homePage.HeroNext).release();
    action.build().perform();
```

I don't believe the sleep will be a part of the action as you intend it. Perhaps divide up into 2 actions if the hard wait is necessary. You might also be able to use dragAndDrop or dragAndDropBy.  One drags to a target element the other to a target location

Answer (score 0):

Use Drag and Drop with x and y coordinates:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.dragAndDropBy(homePage.HeroImage, 200, 0).build().perform();
```

Here driver will perform drag and drop on HeroImage element horizontally. If you want to drag and drop vertically set `x=0` and `y="some range"`.

Hope it works.
Thank you.